# AspNet MVC render server side @Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Im building a dynamic menu in my MVC project so in my controller I have the following:

```
// list accounts
                menu.Add(new Model.Custom.Menu() { Active = true, Url = "dashboard.html", Icon = "mdi mdi-account-card-details", Items = null, Text = "List Accounts" });
```

Right now `dashboard.html` link is hardcoded but I required to be `@Html.ActionLink` so it renders the right path.

> Any clue?

Comment: `Url = Url.Action(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `UrlHelper` to call the Action method which will return the correct relative path to the action method.

```
var url=new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext);
var newUrl = url.Action("Dashboard");
//The above will generate the path to Dashboard action method.

menu.Add(new Model.Custom.Menu() { Active = true, Url = newUrl});
```